# Client-server application socket problem

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I am currently developing a client-server application and I have this problem: I want to create a different class instance depending on what the connected socket sends, but it only creates the first instance then it stucks. Here is some piece of code:

```
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    String buff = null;
    transfer tr = null;
    colectieClienti clienti = new colectieClienti();
```

And:

```
while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = server.accept();
                buff = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))).readLine();
                if (buff.equals("client")) {
                    (colectieClienti.useri[colectieClienti.nrUseri++] = new clientThread(clientSocket, stmt)).start();
                } else {
                    tr = new transfer(clientSocket);
                    tr.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
```

I have to mention that `clientThread` is a class that extends `Thread` and communicates with a GUI, and `transfer` is a class that only send some files from client to server. The logic is something like this: In the GUI the user connects to the server, so it is created a new instance of `clientThread` and after this, when the user press a button it creates a new socket (on the client side and send a message to the server, something like "I want to create a new instance of `transfer` class, which is done by the `buff`) and receive the data. But it only creates the `clientThread` instance and then it stucks. Can anyone help me?

LE: This is the constructor of `clientThread`

```
 public clientThread(Socket socket, Statement statement) {
        comunicare = socket;
        try {
            oStream = comunicare.getOutputStream();
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(comunicare.getInputStream()));
            os = new PrintStream(oStream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        this.statement = statement;
    }
```

Comment: This code is trying to connect an infinite number of times.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: have you tried debugging this? shouldn't `accept`ing the socket be a one-time thing?

Comment: @sthupahsmaht: No, accepting a socket isn't a one-time thing.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Yes, the server is listening for an infinite possible number of clients. The application is server - multiclient.

Comment: What happens when you debug the server code?

Comment: @Kaj: The server works perfectly (it communicates with the GUI OK), but when the GUI creates a new socket, the server accepts the connection and stucks on  `buff = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))).readLine();` (That instruction is never done or it never reaches to this line, but `clientSocket = server.accept();` is done).

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess, but are you sending a line terminator from the client?  BufferedReader.readLine() reads until it gets a \n, \r, or a \r\n, so if the client is not writing that, the server will just wait.

Comment: On the client side I have this: `output = new PrintWriter(client2.getOutputStream());
                    output.println("transfer");` , so I don't think it is from "\n".

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: [avoid extending the thread class and opt out for implementing a runnable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/java-implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

> But it only creates the clientThread instance and then it stucks. Can anyone help me?

Then show us what you do when you create the `clientThread`, showing us what you do on the server (alone) is not enough for us to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Ionut and where does it get stuck?

Comment: @Lirik: After the second socket is created in the server side. `clientSocket = server.accept();`

Comment: @Ionut the `accept()` call blocks until a client attempts to make a connection. How many times is your client attempting to connect? If it only connects once (which it should be, unless you get disconnected), then the server will block until it gets another connection.

Comment: @Lirik: Not the `accept()` statement is the problem. But never mind ... I've tried something else. I couldn't find the solution for this problem. :(

Comment: @Ionut I have a feeling that you're not doing something right. The accept statement is **not** the problem?!? If I undersatnd you correctly you're telling me that `server.accept()` was blocking (which is exactly what it's supposed to do until a client connects).

Comment: @Lirik: No, not the `server.accept()` was blocking. Reading from the socket was blocking.